# Include header only once at the top of a rolling file

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

Is it possible to only include header information at the top of a rolling file?

I have the following config file:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="d:\temp\TTTest.log"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <header value="[Header]&#13;&#10;" />
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-25utcdate{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}%-20property{log4net:HostName}%-30logger%-30thread%-7level%message%newline"/>
            </layout>
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
            <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
            <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
            <countDirection value="1"/>
        </appender>
```

When I run my application, for example twice I get header information twice e.g.

```
 [Header] 
 The Log line
 [Header]
 The Log line 
 etc
```

I am looking to achieve the following:

```
 [Header] 
 The Log line
 The Log line 
 etc
```

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way I've found to do this is to create a class that inherits from RollingFileAppender and overwrites like this the WriteHeader method :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Util;
using log4net.Appender;

namespace CsvLogging
{
    public class HeaderOnceAppender : RollingFileAppender 
    {
        protected override void WriteHeader()
        {
            try
            {
                if (LockingModel.AcquireLock().Length == 0)
                {
                    base.WriteHeader();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                LockingModel.ReleaseLock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then use this class as appender :

```
<appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="CsvLogging.HeaderOnceAppender">
```

Comment: I needed to add the assembly for the type as well, as log4net didn't know where to look
<appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="CvsLogging.HeaderOnceAppender, CvsLoggingAssembly">

Answer (score 3):

Create a concrete implementation of the log4net.Layout.PatternLayout :

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    using log4net.Layout;

    public class MyConcretePatternLayout : PatternLayout
    {
        public override string Header => "My Header text here"
    }
}
```

Modify your log4net.config file to use this new custom pattern layout :

```
    <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      ...
      <layout type="MyApplication.MyConcretePatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern...
      </layout>

    </appender>
```

Now whenever the file rolls due to your criteria you should see
"My Header text here" at the top of each file.

Answer (score 2):

With the help from the previous answers I managed to resolve my problem, what i needed was to put everything in the code without having the properites file for configuration RollingFileAppender.

```
public class MyConcretePatternLayout : PatternLayout
{
   public override string Header => "Header"
}



public class HeaderAppender : RollingFileAppender
    {
        protected override void WriteHeader()
        {
            try
            {
                if (LockingModel.AcquireLock().Length == 0)
                {
                    base.WriteHeader();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    LockingModel.ReleaseLock();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally what I did is was the following:

```
RollingFileAppender roller = new HeaderAppender
                {
                    Name = "CustomAppender",
                    AppendToFile = true,
                    File = "..\\logs\\" + "test.log",
                    MaxSizeRollBackups = -1,
                    LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock(),
                    RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Composite,
                    StaticLogFileName = false,
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom appender that inherits from RollingFileAppender.  See the post below.

[Log4net - How to know when a file is rolled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228060/log4net-how-to-know-when-a-file-is-rolled)

Basically, you need to provide your own logic in the custom appender to write your header to each new file.  You'd probably do this in RollOverSize.  Would be a good idea to get a copy of log4net source code for reference.