# How to programmatically determine when a rollover happened in log4j?

Tags: log4j

I am attempting to use log4j to write CSV files. The CSV header must be written to the top of a log file every time it is created. For example, all of these rolled files must have the following as the first line in the log file:

> log.0 Timestamp, Name, min, max
>
> log.1 Timestamp, Name, min, max
>
> log.2 Timestamp, Name, min, max

Is it possible to determine when a rollover has occurred so that I can append the header?

Thanks.

P.S: I know there are lots of open source CSV writers but I prefer not to use them because I would like to use the existing log functionality in our software.

Comment: That does not sound like a good idea. For example, if you have multiple classes logging, or if your application is multithreaded, or distributed. Let's assume that the event you are talking about (detecting when a log file is rolled) exists and is detectable. There is no guarantee that the writes to the log will be ordered, i.e., that your handler will be able to append the header to the next log file before the actual log entry that generated the roll. I would stick with other means, like always inserting the header to files manually/through a script.

Comment: Good point. In my case, the CSV logging go through a single class and I can guarantee synchronization. Looking at the RollingFileAppender source, it turns out there is no public API to determine that a rollover happened. In fact, it simply checks if the current log file has reached its max, a copy of it, deletes the current file, creates another file with the specified file name and starts logging into it. However RollingFileAppender.getFile() can be used to know the current file name used by the appender and you can check the time stamp on the file to know if a rollover happened.

Comment: And what about inserting (through a script or similar) the header to all of your log files at once, from outside your application?

Comment: I'm not sure if the code for log4j is similar to log4net, but here's a post for the same question that was asked about log4net. Maybe it's helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228060/log4net-how-to-know-when-a-file-is-rolled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at log4j documentation for RollingFileAppender, it has a method called rollOver.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html

You would need to implement a custom file appender that inherits from RollingFileAppender, and override the rollOver method.  I imagine you could just call super.rollOver, and then write whatever you want as a header to the new file before anything gets logged to it.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I ended up doing. I just copy pasted RollingFileAppender code and added a counter which increments every time a rollover occurred. It would have been nice to have this in RollingFileAppender itself.

Comment: Glad I could help (that is, if you didn't figure this out on your own before I answered).  If this is the right answer, can you mark it as correct please?

Comment: How to configure that the logger will use my implemented class?

Answer (score 0):

I use this one

```
public class MyRoller extends RollingFileAppender {

@Override
public void rollover() {
    super.rollover();

    final LoggingEvent event = new LoggingEvent();
    event.setMessage("CSV_HEADER;1;2;3;4;...");
    event.setLevel(Level.INFO);

    append(event);
}
```

}